# How to ge subdomain for Marketing Cloud API?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to use a connected application in order to interact with Marketing Cloud API.

As far as I understand from the following docs:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/your-subdomain-tenant-specific-endpoints.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/install-packages.html

In order to do it I need to:

1. Create a package.
2. Add an "API Integration" component which will reveal the subdomain.

(In addition I need to create a connected app so that I have client-id and client-secret, I have already did that, so this part if fine).

The problem is that I don't have an "API Integration" component in the list of components.

The salesForce account that I'm using is an Admin, if it matters.
[image]

After I create a package, if I click on the component list, I get a very long list but none of the options isn't "API Integration", see pic:

[image]

And in a more general note, all the tutorials that I follow are showing a bit different salesForce UI than the one I see. For instance, in all places it look like the creation of a package is done from the "Installed Packages" section, but on my UI, I can only see a "New" button on the "Package Manager" section.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to **Marketing Cloud** to create the package

1. In Marketing Cloud, go to Setup | Apps | Installed Packages.
2. Click New.
3. Give the package a name and description.
4. Save the package. After the package is saved, you can view the package details. See Installed Packages Definitions for more information about each field. You see the Package ID, JWT Signing Secret, and Source Account only for packages created in your account.
5. Under Components, click Add Component, and select a component.

After you finish the steps, you will see a page with information where you can get the subdomain

For example:

```
Authentication Base URI
https://YourSubdomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/
```

Reference: [Installed Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/install-packages.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying, how do i go to marketing? feel stupid but can you please provide a link?

Comment: @Noam I assume you already have the credentials to access to your Marketing Cloud then log in to your account at https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud/

Comment: I don't think I have an account, or at the very least I don't remember I created one. I don't see any option there to create an account either. How am I suppose to do it?

Comment: @Noam Marketing Cloud doesn't have a free/trial version, so you cannot just create an account. In case, your company does have one, then you may need to ask your Marketing Cloud admin to create the MC access account for you

Comment: Ok, we don't currently have a market cloud account, so I'll have to create one, even if it costs money, the only question is - how?

Comment: @Noam you would need to contact with Salesforce. Maybe this form may help https://www.salesforce.com/ap/form/contact/contactme-marketing-cloud/

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help.